# oracle sql - best date format to join to Excel date column

Tags: oracle

Oracle date format is in date time format: '4/5/2017 12:00:00 AM'
Excel worksheet that has a date format of '04/05/2017'

I am trying to join these together using the best format.

I've tried:

extract(year from T1.H_DATE) || extract(month from T1.H_DATE) || extract(day from T1.H_DATE) JOIN_DATE

and also

Round(cast(extract(year from T1.H_DATE) || extract(month from T1.H_DATE) || extract(day from T1.H_DATE) as Numeric)) EXCEL_JOIN_DATE

And I tried converting my excel date into text(A1,"yyyymd"), but I am getting an error trying to join a Numeric Decimal to a Numeric Whole Number.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `trunc(T1.H_DATE)`? That will return the date without the time portion of the date. [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Comment: Trunc doesn't seem to work. The underlying database format still has time included. What if I converted it to number or string? Is there a good equivalent in Excel?

Comment: to_number(to_char(T1.H_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')) - How do I remove the decimal from this?